# Dinamically set the asp-route-* attribute

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to make a context menu (appears when I right-click a list element) that deletes (or edits, etc) an element. But I need to pass the id of the element to the controller so I can delete it from the database and since there's only one menu I can't set the `asp-route-id` attribute to a certain value.

I put a custom attribute on each element that stores its id and I can access it in javascript, but I can't pass it to the `asp-route-id` attribute. Is there a way to do it? And if not, is there any other way to send the id to the controller?

UPDATE:

Controller named Feature(just the Delete action)

```
    ...
    public void Delete(string id)
    {
        //work with id
    }
    ...
```

Javascript

```
    function deleteFeature(event) {
        var Id = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("featureId");
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/Feature/Delete",
           data: Id,
           success: function (result) {
               alert("Yes");
           },
           error: function (result) {
               alert("Nope");
           }
        });
     }
```

The id is passed correctly as a string, I tested but the rest doesn't work. I tried with JSON.strigify and putting an object in data. In some cases I got the 'Yes' message but still no output. I also don't know if the page I'm currently on matters.

Comment: `asp-route-id` is something the tag helper uses at server side. it basically add a querystring (route param) to your url for the key `id`. You can do the samething in javascript.

Comment: I see. How can I do it in javascript though? I searched on the internet and found a way with jquery ($.ajax) but I'm not sure how I should use that. Let's say I have the controller Features and the action Delete with an id of a feature as parameter. I have the id in javascript. How do I send it to the action Delete?

Comment: it depends on what you url you want to call, what value you want to pass, how will you get that value and when ? Share the relevant code in the question and then we can help. With the details you provided so far,it is hard to write an answer.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Never mind, it actually was working the whole time but it wasn't redirecting me automatically so I thought it didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion to pass directly in javascript.